# How do I combine two PDO statements for INSERT into database?

Tags: php, database, arrays, pdo

I am looking to use the output from one pdo statement with the array data of another statement. At the moment both set of statements work fine individually but I don't know how I can go about merging the outputs into one table on my database.

The database table I am trying to update has 3 columns, `recipe_id`, `item_number` and `quantity`.

What I need is for `$recipeID` to be used as the main `recipe_id` and the outputs from my array to fill the other two columns. Hopefully I am making sense and someone can help, the code I am using is shown below with comments:

```
<?php
        //MySQL Database Connect
        require 'config.php';

        //Takes form input for recipe title for insert to the recipe table
        $name = $_POST["recipeName"];

        //Stored procedure inputs the recipe name to the recipe table and outputs a recipe_id which is to be passed into recipe item table below
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare( "CALL sp_add_recipe(:name, @output)" );
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        //Execute Statment
        $stmt->execute();

        //$recipeID variable stores recipe_id outputted from the stored procedure above
        $recipeID = $dbh->query( "SELECT @output" )->fetchColumn(); 

        //Insert places the values from $recipeID, item_number & quantity into the recipe_item table
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO recipe_item (recipe_id, item_number, quantity) VALUES (:recipeID,?,?)');
        $stmt ->bindParam(':recipeID',$recipeID, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        //Ingredients variable combines array values from HTML form
        $ingredients = array_combine($_POST['recipe']['ingredient'], $_POST['recipe']['quantity']);

        //Each value from the form is inserted to the recipe_item table as defined above
        foreach($ingredients as $name => $quantity)
        {
            $stmt->execute(); //I would like to insert $recipeID to my database with each line of the array below.
            $stmt->execute(array($name, $quantity)); 
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: There is no need to use `mysql_escape_string` in this scenario any more (actually, it's wrong and likely to break the string). PDO does the job of escaping in the prepared statement

Comment: @Pekka thanks for the update, I will update my code, still getting to grips with PDO. If you have any idea on how I might go about getting the output I am after it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with current code?

Comment: Hi @galymzhan at the moment the first statement is correctly inserting the recipe name to my main recipe table and outputting the id to $recipeID but when I try to include this in the foreach loop with the array nothing happens. If I exclude the $recipeID an execute the foreach loop on its own with just the array the $name and $quantity update in the database correctly but it's missing the $recipeID (or it just inserts it as 0). Any ideas would be great...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO recipe_item (recipe_id, item_number, quantity) VALUES (:recipeID,:number,:quantity)');

//remove the bindParam() call for recipeId

$ingredients = array_combine($_POST['recipe']['ingredient'], $_POST['recipe']['quantity']);

foreach ($ingredients as $name => $quantity) {
    $bound = array(
        'recipeID' => $recipeID,
        'number' => $name, // ?? This is what your codes does at the moment, but looks weird
        'quantity' => $quantity
    );
    $stmt->execute($bound);
}
```